# How to acquire a lock file in Linux Bash

Tags: linux, bash, locking, locks

I have an existing lock file sometimes used by other processes. I want to temporarily acquire this lock file so other programs that potentially use it have to wait for me to unlock. Then I want to run a few commands, and then unlock it. How do I do this? I thought this would be easy but for some reason I cannot figure it out at all. I understand that I would most likely need to use `flock` for this, but what arguments should I be using in this scenario? `flock` seems to always need a command or second file to work, however in this situation there doesn't seem to be one.

Context: A bash script I am using is running into race conditions around a particular lock file (`/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` to be specific), and to test my solution I want to reliably be able to lock this file so I can check if my changes to the script work.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) is an overview on the topic. Look especially at the sectons labelled _Problems_ and _Lock files_

Answer (score 3):

You have an example in the [flock (1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) man page. You should execute the commands in a subshell:

```
(
    flock -n 9 || exit 1
    ...
) 9>/var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

Using this form the lock is released when the subshell exits.

Comment: Command doesn't work. `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock: Permission denied`

Comment: You need write permission on the file, which for `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` means that you must be `root`.